# CFWheels - Order = "random" is throwing a column error

Tags: mysql, sql, railo, cfwheels, cfml

For some reason, when I specify "random" in my order clause of findAll(), CFWHeels throws an error:

> **Wheels.ColumnNotFound**
>
> Wheels looked for the column mapped to the **random** property but
>   couldn't find it in the database table. Suggested action
>
> Verify the **order** argument and/or your **property** to column mappings done
>   with the property method inside the model's **init** method to make sure
>   everything is correct.

I have used calculated properties before, but this shouldn't be looking for any of that with regard to "random" ordering.

```
<cffunction name="random">

    <cfparam name="params.page" default="1" />
    <cfparam name="params.pageQuantity" default="5" />

    <cfset posts = model("post").findAll(

        select = "

            posts.postID,
            postTitle,
            postPoints,
            postAuthority,
            postCreated,

            postCommentCount,
            postUpVoteCount,
            postDownVoteCount,

            users.userID,
            userName,

            categories.categoryID,
            categoryTitle,
            categoryToken",

        include     = "user,category", 
        order       = "random",
        page        = params.page,
        perPage     = params.pageQuantity

    ) />

</cffunction>
```

Does this possibly have something to do with using a `select` statement?

Would appreciate any help.

Many thanks,
Michael.

Comment: What sql does this generate?  What happens if you run that sql directly against your db?

Comment: @DanBracuk I am unable to view the SQL generated, as this is a CFWheels error page and not a Railo error - is there any way I can do this?

Comment: It might be a CFWheels error page but it sure looks like a database error.  Does your database support "order by random" when random is neither a fieldname nor an alias from your select clause?

Comment: @DanBracuk I am using Railo with MySQL. I just tried running a simple random select on the DB directly and it works just fine. "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY rand()". Any ideas? Does CFWheels support this on MySQL? Or is there a better way altogether to achieve this?

Comment: If "order by rand()" works in mySQL, the first thing I would try is "order = 'rand()'" in the wheels function.

Comment: @DanBracuk Weirdly, that solved it! Thank you. I assumed CFWheels was using an aliased keyword of its own called "random" that was cross-database, since that is what is shown in the docs for this. Using order="rand()" works as expected! Turn your comment into an answer and I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As established in the commments.

If `order by rand()` works in mySQL, the first thing I would try is `order = 'rand()'` in the wheels function.